# PulseAudio: How to determine native sample rates and bit depths, supported by hardware?

Tags: audio, hardware, pulseaudio

I want to set maximum sampling rate and bit depth supported by my hardware (Intel HDA).

How to know the values?

I need this information because I want to avoid unnecessary resampling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like those information could be queried with `grep` as follows:

```bsh
grep rates /proc/asound/card0/codec\#0
grep bits /proc/asound/card0/codec\#0
# or in one-line with '-P'
grep -P 'rates|bits' /proc/asound/card0/codec\#0
```

Please note that `\` is used to escape `#`.
Actual file name is `codec#0`.

Above commands will show you something like below:

```bsh
$ grep -P 'rates|bits' /proc/asound/card0/codec\#0
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
```

Although the result looks correct, but actually I'm not sure whether it's a correct way to query.

Comment: Can you please provide any additional information or links to prove that these parameters are truly supported by hardware and aren't just software compatibility modes of audio subsystem or audio drier? The output of commands you provided seems to be correct, but I am just not completely sure.

Comment: @shitpoet Unfortunately, I don't have any rationale for the answer.  It's just found by exploring `/proc` directory.  I hope someone else would add information supporting the use of `/proc/asound/card?/codec#?`.

Comment: What if the sound card in question [doesn't have](https://gist.github.com/nickolai/e1118602977542504e20da55e43632a2#file-my_soundcards_1-log) the codec#0 file? On my system there are 4 sound cards: two do have the file and two don't (including the one I want to play music through, the E-MU Tracker Pre USB, card2 of 3). I poked around with mc and there's no similarly named file in the 'card2' or 'card3' directories.

Comment: On some systems, the current sample rate may be available in `cat /proc/asound/cardX/pcm0(p|c)/sub0/hw_params` (where P = playback, C = capture)

Comment: I've noticed that a very similar method is used in one of Archlinux Wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#High_latency_with_USB_DACs_(e.g._Schiit_DACs), so I mark it as the accepted answer. Although the wiki recommends `/proc/asound/cardX/steramY` instead of `/proc/asound/cardX/codec`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio#Features), Intel HDA has sample rates of 6–192 kHz and sample resolutions of 8–32 bits, though manufacturers may have not implemented the full specification, so it is good idea to test using

```
pactl list sinks | grep -Ei 'name:|sample specification:'
```

after changing the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#High_latency_with_USB_DACs_(e.g._Schiit_DACs))

> You can check what your DAC supports by querying ALSA:
>
> First get the card number of your DAC:
>
> ```
> $ aplay -l
> ...
> card 3: S2 [Schiit Hel 2], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
>   Subdevices: 0/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
> ...
> ```
>
> So in this example it would be card 3. Get all supported sample rates and formats:
>
> ```
> $ cat /proc/asound/cardX/streamX
> ...
> Playback:
>   ...
>   Interface 1
>     Altset 1
>     Format: S16_LE
>     Channels: 2
>     Endpoint: 0x05 (5 OUT) (ASYNC)
>     Rates: 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000, 352800, 384000
>     Data packet interval: 125 us
>     Bits: 16
>     ...
>   Interface 1
>     Altset 2
>     Format: S24_3LE
>     Channels: 2
>     Endpoint: 0x05 (5 OUT) (ASYNC)
>     Rates: 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000, 352800, 384000
>     Data packet interval: 125 us
>     Bits: 24
>     ...
>   Interface 1
>     Altset 3
>     Format: S32_LE
>     Channels: 2
>     Endpoint: 0x05 (5 OUT) (ASYNC)
>     Rates: 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000, 352800, 384000
>     Data packet interval: 125 us
>     Bits: 32
>     ...
> ...
> ```
>
> In this case S16_LE, S24_3LE, S32_LE are the supported formats and 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000, 352800, 384000 are the supported sample rates across all formats.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pamcd list-sinks`,

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:\|Hz'
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
```

Comment: Output of this command changes if I change `default-sample-rate` in pulseaudio config `daemon.conf`, but I want to know maximum hardware supported setting. From the other side when I set `default-sample-rate` to `60000` the output was still at `48000`. Maybe this mean that 48k is maximum hardware supported sample rate?